# Python 3.5: OrderedDict -- overwrite the order of self when sorted?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, ordereddictionary

#### Goal

To overwrite the ordering of a class that inherits from `OrderedDict` when sorted.

#### Description

I have a class that inherits from `OrderedDict`.

From the [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) documentation, it is clear that one can get a sorted `OrderedDict` by initializing a new one on the sorted list of key, value tuples:

```
OrderedDict(sorted(my_ordered_dict, key=lambda item: item[1]))
```

This is nifty and all, **but** because `OrderedDict` remembers the insertion order *even* when a key is overwritten, one can **not** simply add a method:

```
def sort_by_value(self):
    self = OrderedDict(sorted(my_ordered_dict, key=lambda item: item[1]))
```

to change the ordering of the original `OrderedDict`.

The documentation also suggests:

```
def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    if key in self:
        del self[key]
    OrderedDict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
```

for ''an ordered dictionary variant that remembers the order the keys were last inserted.'' Which is not ideal, but would yield the behavior that is desired.

I have made a dummy class trying this idea. However it does not work.  How can I overwrite the ordering of `OrderedDict` once it has been sorted?

#### Dummy Class

```
from collections import OrderedDict
class DumbDictionary(OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DumbDictionary, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self:
            del self[key]
        DumbDictionary.__setitem__(self, key, value)

    def sort_by_value(self):
        self = DumbDictionary(sorted(self.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately overwriting self doesn't work as it breaks the reference to the original object. Thus one can achieve the desired result by using `super` in conjunction with one of `OrderedDict`'s methods as follows:

```
def sort_by_value(self):
    post_sort =sorted(self.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]))
    for key, value in post_sort:
        super(DumbDictionary, self).move_to_end(key)
```